# Lowest divisible number in number string

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility

A number is arranged in a pattern like: 12345678910111213141516...

What is the lowest value of that pattern divisible by 72?

They are single numbers, not seperate (i.e. first in sequence is 1, second is 12, third, 123 etc)

Comment: To be divisible by 72, it is necessary and sufficient for the number to be divisible by both 8 and 9.  Do you know any way to tell if a number is divisible by 8 or by 9?

Answer (score 1):

The first such numbers are $a_{36}$, $a_{44}$, $a_{144}$, $a_{152}$, $a_{216}$, ... So the lowest is $123\ldots343536$.

Comment: How would one go about finding those numbers without testing out every single instance though?